# 2 NAS drives, 2 different speeds on network

Tags: networking, raid, nas

I have a WD NAS drive, I can move files to and from it at about 125 MB/s. I have a Netgear NAS drive, I can move files to and from it at about 30 to 35 MB/s. From the same pc, connected to the same Gigabit network switch (all hardware is Gigabit, and cables are cat 7).

WD is a single drive, Netgear is a 4 drive RAID5.

My question I suppose is: Does the fact that it's RAID5 make a difference to transfer rates? And, should I expect more speedy transfers from it or try a different RAID flavour?

Comment: RAID levels can make a difference. And RIAD5 is not max performance, just max storage with minimal redudancy. But before you try changing that look at the other options. E.g. is the Netgear running at gigabit speeds.

Comment: Also worth noting that RAID 5 will typically only exhibit a performance penalty on writes and wouldn't normally slow down reads, especially not by that much.

Comment: thank you Giacomo for editing my question to make it more your question than mine.

Comment: the netgear drive is clearly not functioning at gigabit speed, and netgear are unwilling to help me solve the issue, and as such they do not deserve capitalisation as Western Digital do, because they actually provide a product that works. i asked netgear to help me regarding any software options i may have missed, and any hardware issues i should be aware of regarding slow transfer speeds, they were hopeless, that's why i am asking for help here.